# How to get data in dashboard with Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm scraping some data about car renting from getaround.com. I recently saw that it was possible to get cars availability with scrapy-splash from a calendar rendered with Javascript. An example is given in this url :

https://fr.getaround.com/location-voiture/liege/ford-fiesta-533656

The information I need is contained in the `div` tag with class `owner_calendar_month`. However, I saw that some data seem to be accessible in the `div` tag with class `js_car_calendar calendar_large`, in which the attribute `data-path` specify `/dashboard/cars/533656/calendar`. Do you know how to access this path ? And to scrape the data within it using Scrapy ?

Answer (score 1):

If you visit `https://fr.getaround.com/dashboard/cars/533656/calendar` you get an error saying you have to be logged in to view the data. So first of all you would have to create a method in Scrapy to sign in to the website if you want to be able to scrape that data.

Comment: I've already tried this solution, it does not work. It just sends an empty page saying "There is nothing here". Is it possible that this specific data source is private or hidden ?

Comment: Probably, seems like the calendar is rendered on the server. So you would have to go into the calendar elements on the page to get the data, which is usually very hard.